# Linq query to exclude related entities that are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my current project I want to display a list of entries which have related ICollections with them. Plant has many-to-many relation with both BadNeighbours and GoodNeighbours. The Linq statement I use is:

```
ICollection<Plant> plants = _context.Plants
                .Include(p => p.BadNeighbours)
                .Include(p => p.GoodNeighbours)
                .ToList();
```

This displays all the entries from the Plants table with the related plants. However, I want to exclude plants from the list that have neither GoodNeighbours or BadNeighbours.

These are the entities:
Plants

```
public class Plant
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GoodPlants> GoodNeighbours { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BadPlants> BadNeighbours { get; set; }
}
```

BadNeighbours

```
public class BadPlants
{
    public int PlantId { get; set; }
    public int BadNeighbourId { get; set; }

    public virtual Plant Plant { get; set; }
    public virtual Plant BadNeighbour { get; set; }
}
```

GoodNeighbours

```
public class GoodPlants
{
    public int PlantId { get; set; }
    public int GoodNeighbourId { get; set; }

    public virtual Plant Plant { get; set; }
    public virtual Plant GoodNeighbour {get; set;}
}
```

EntityBuilder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
   modelBuilder.Entity<BadPlants>()
    .HasKey(u => new { u.BadNeighbourId, u.PlantId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<GoodPlants>()
    .HasKey(u => new { u.GoodNeighbourId, u.PlantId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>()
    .HasMany(p => p.GoodNeighbours)
    .WithOne(g => g.Plant)
    .HasForeignKey(g => g.PlantId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>()
   .HasMany(p => p.BadNeighbours)
   .WithOne(b => b.Plant)
   .HasForeignKey(b => b.PlantId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);            
}
```

I tried to add `Where(p => p.GoodNeighbours.Count() > 0 && p.BadNeighbours.Count() > 0)` after the last `include` statement and although this results in the correct number of plants in my `ICollection plants`, the relations GoodNeighbours and BadNeighbours are no longer included.

What Linq statement can I use for my purpose?
Thnx

Comment: can you post Plant model and dependent models?

Comment: See my edited post above

Comment: This post might answer your query [how-to-load-the-navigation-property-with-ef-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065489/how-to-load-the-navigation-property-with-ef-core)

Comment: I get the error that lambda expression is not a valid expression within `Include` statement. I tried: `.Include(p => p.BadNeighbours.Where(bn => bn.PlantId == p.Id || bn.BadNeighbourId == p.Id))`

Comment: You should show the entire query, not only the `Where`. Maybe you have a `Select` that makes EF ignore the `Includes`.

Comment: But I doubt the usefulness of your model. I assume that a `GoodPlant` is still a `Plant`. What do you do when a plant is both `Plant` and `GoodPlant`? Also, this isn't many-to-many. You have two 1:n relationships off of `Plant`. But many-to-many between `Plant`s may be more appropriate here.

Comment: No, I don't use a select. The `.Include(...)` in my comment is from my original query above. It might very well that my model is wrong. I meant to use a self referential model. Any plant can be a good neighbour or bad neighbour of a given plant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that might work out

```cs
ICollection<Plant> plants = _context.Plants
   .Where(p => !_context.BadPlants.Any(nb => nb.PlantId == p.Id || nb.BadNeighbourId == p.Id))
   .Where(p => !_context.GoodPlants.Any(nb => nb.PlantId == p.Id || nb.GoodNeighbourId == p.Id))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the full list as well, including the plants with no relations.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Still, the related navigational properties are not loaded. I cannot access the names of the related plants in the collection.

Comment: Do you mean `_context.Plants.Select(pr => pr.Name)` returns list of empty values?