# ProjectTo - Value cannot be null . (Parameter 'source')

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The following code leads to a `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')` exception. It is caused by `.ProjectTo` and more specifically it is caused by `DisciplineHours` in `DisciplineDto`. It's probably hard to tell what's causing it, but how do I trace it back?

It's probably smt like `.ThenInclude(discipline => discipline.DisciplineHours)`.

> fail: AcademicSchedule.Application.Disciplines.Queries.GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery[0]
> Request: Unhandled Exception for Request GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery AcademicSchedule.Application.Disciplines.Queries.GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
> at lambda_method274(Closure , Discipline )
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

```cs
using Response = List<DisciplineDto>;

public class GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery : IRequest<Response>
{
    public int FlowId { get; set; }
}

public class GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery, Response>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQueryHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Task<Response> Handle(GetDisciplinesByFlowIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var flow = _context.Flows
            .Include(f => f.Disciplines)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.FlowId);

        if (flow == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Flow), request.FlowId);
        }

        var result = flow.Disciplines
            .AsQueryable()
            .ProjectTo<DisciplineDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToList();

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DisciplineDto : IMapFrom<Discipline>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string DisciplineCode { get; set; }

    public int SemesterNumber { get; set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    public string CurriculumCode { get; set; }

    public int CurriculumVersion { get; set; }

    public DepartmentDto Department { get; set; }
    public PeriodDto Period { get; set; }
    public List<DisciplineHourDto> DisciplineHours { get; set; } // Caused by this line
}

public class Discipline
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string DisciplineCode { get; set; }
    public int SemesterNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string CurriculumCode { get; set; }
    public int CurriculumVersion { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }
    public Period Period { get; set; }

    public List<Flow> Flows { get; set; }
    public List<DisciplineHour> DisciplineHours { get; set; }
    public List<ClassActivity> ClassActivities { get; set; }
}

public class Flow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PeriodId { get; set; }
    public Period Period { get; set; }

    public List<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public List<Subgroup> Subgroups { get; set; }
    public List<ClassActivity> ClassActivities { get; set; }
}

public class DisciplineHour
{
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public Discipline Discipline { get; set; }

    public int ClassActivityTypeId { get; set; }
    public ClassActivityType ClassActivityType { get; set; }

    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
}

public class DisciplineHourDto : IMapFrom<DisciplineHour>
{
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }

    public int ClassActivityTypeId { get; set; }

    public decimal Hours { get; set; }

    public string DisciplineName { get; set; }

    public string ClassActivityTypeName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<DisciplineHour, DisciplineHourDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.DisciplineName, opt => opt.MapFrom(sh => sh.Discipline.FullName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ClassActivityTypeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(sh => sh.ClassActivityType.ShortName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(sh => $"{sh.ClassActivityType.FullName} {sh.Discipline.ShortName}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, I'm using the following CleanArchitecture implementation https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Application/Common/Mappings/MappingProfile.cs#L13

Comment: `_context.Flows.Include(f => f.Disciplines).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.FlowId)` executes your query, from there on, you are working in memory, not on database. `flow.Disciplines.AsQueryable()` does not magically allow you to query your database again. You only have what you loaded before: `Disciplines` without nested navigation properties like `DisciplineHours`. As far as I understand the situation, EF core would not lazy-load missing properties for you.

Comment: @grek40, that's right. How do I deal with that in that case? I need to get all disciplines by flow id. The thing is that it is many to many and there is no separate table for it. I can provide the model in the question.

Comment: What happens when you `_context.Flows.Include(f => f.Disciplines).ThenInclude(d => d.DisciplineHours).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.FlowId)`?

Comment: @grek40, now `ProjectTo` returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, not `Value cannot be null`.

Comment: Does DisciplineHours in turn have more navigation properties that are expected to be not null in the mapping configuration? You should provide more information about your model.

Comment: @grek40, take a look at `DisciplineHourDto`. It depends on `Discipline` and `ClassActivityType`. Basically two more `.ThenInclude`s. The problem is that when I do that, the framework won't allow me to, because it's like Flows.Disciplines => DisciplineHours => Discipline & ClassActivityType is too much.

Comment: Your basic options: (1) load all required data into memory before mapping or (2) project before materializing: write a query that doesn't materialize before the mapping takes place. For (2) you could try something like `_context.Disciplines.Where(d => d.Flows.Any(f => f.Id == request.FlowId)).ProjectTo<DisciplineDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();` but whether it works depends on the details of your mapping definition.

Comment: @grek40, mate thanks a lot! `_context.Disciplines.Where(d => d.Flows.Any(f => f.Id == request.FlowId)).ProjectTo<DisciplineDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();` worked. Please write that as an answer.

Comment: @grek40, please summarize all of your comments, that's a very good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error appears because your SQL query doesn't load the `Discipline.DisciplineHours` property and EF Core doesn't lazy-load the property for you on demand.

When working with automapper you have to decide whether you want to project on the sql query level or map in memory after all data are retrieved from the database.

Writing the projection for the sql query becomes easier when you start with the root entity of your projection. So, instead of starting your query with `_context.Flows`, start your query with `_context.Disciplines` and find a condition that's logically equivalent to your original query condition. Project your query to the desired DTO before materializing the data like

```
var result = _context.Disciplines
    .Where(d => d.Flows.Any(f => f.Id == request.FlowId))
    .ProjectTo<DisciplineDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .ToList();
```

This only works when Automapper is configured in a way that doesn't require any client side functions. Otherwise you would need to load the whole model into memory first. This can be done with **eager loading** using `_context.Flows.Include(x => x.Disciplines).ThenInclude(y => y.DisciplineHours)...` until all required data are loaded.

If the object graph is to complex for complete eager loading, you can also partially load the data initially, and then load more parts in separate queries. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068336/5265292 for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much once again mate! Very good explanation